# python: multiply two columns of nd-arrays to get the vector of same dimensions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following code:

```
 x = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10,2))
 y = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10,2))
```

x and y are `10 x 2` matrix. Now I want to multiply second column of x and y. I did
`z = x[:,1] * y[:,1].` I got the result but z is `1 x 10` array instead of `10 x 1` array. Is there any way such that I get the result direct in the form of `10 x 1` without need to transpose it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of getting the exact column use slicing, that way shape will be preserved:

```
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 2))
>>> y = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10, 2))
>>> x[:,1:2] * y[:,1:2]
array([[36],
       [ 0],
       [ 0],
       [45],
       [ 5],
       [28],
       [ 5],
       [12],
       [56],
       [ 6]])
```